# I removed my email and nick from gitconfig, but it's still able to commit

Tags: git

I've removed my credentials from `~/.gitconfig`, but when I run `git commit -m "some crap"` it still commits with my name.

How can I stop it from being able to commit? I need to test some feature in my program where it requires a `git commit`command to fail.

Comment: maybe its credentials scope is project not global. check your project's .gitconfig or run `git config user.name "YOUR NAME"`. That would override your project specific configurations.

Answer (score 4):

`Git` takes author's e-mail from several places and if it doesn't find it in any of these places it will create it on its own. See `man git-config`:

```
   user.email
       Your email address to be recorded in any newly created commits. Can be overridden by the GIT_AUTHOR_EMAIL,
       GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL, and EMAIL environment variables. See git-commit-tree(1).
```

So, as said in the above comment, first check if you have e-mail configured in `.git/config`, next check all variables listed in the manpage. It's hard to make `git commit` fail because of lack of e-mail because even if it's not explicitly set it's possible to make a commit, at least on `Linux`:

```
$ touch 1243
$ git add 1243
$ git commit -mm
[email-test eab3127] m
 Committer: Arkadiusz Drabczyk <ja@comp.a>
Your name and email address were configured automatically based
on your username and hostname. Please check that they are accurate.
You can suppress this message by setting them explicitly:

    git config --global user.name "Your Name"
    git config --global user.email you@example.com

After doing this, you may fix the identity used for this commit with:

    git commit --amend --reset-author

 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 1243
$ echo $?
0
```

**EDIT:** That being said, I *prefer* to set my e-mail using `EMAIL` variable because it's also understood by other programs such as `doxygen` or `mutt` and not only `git`.

Comment: @Arkdaiusz, thanks for your answer. The deal is that I need to test reported bug with our software where user says that if we set credentials like this `git config --global user.name '""` the software will fail when commiting. So, you're saying that this is impossible? Also, I can use only plain `git commit` command, but I can remove and should remove any credentials to cause the bug. I will ask him for providing more info.